# Trapped in a room with Cobalt 60 - what is the best position to minimize dose?

Tags: radiation

Been thinking of an old TV series I once saw that involved a man being trapped in a room with a Co60 source of (presumably) high activity. So, assuming no escape and nowhere to throw or hide the Co60, how does he minimize the dose he gets in order to maximize survival chances?

If he stands vertically it's an even full body dose.

Does curling up in a ball reduce the overall dose because of the smaller cross section?

How about absolute minimum cross section by lying down feet facing the source?

Comment: This is probably largely a bio question.

Comment: A praying position might be a good idea. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne foxhole conversion, happens me every turbulent flight. I was going to suggest putting the source into one shoe then taking the other shoe apart, then wrapping all your clothes around it. OK, you will get cold, but the cobalt will sort that for you. Or ring McGyver.

Comment: The Particle Data Booklet says the radiation length of water (used as a proxy for flesh) is about $36\,\mathrm{cm}$, so your legs can shield your core to a small, but non-trivial extent in grenade survival position. Though that *does* mean using your gonads as shielding for the organs in your upper torso. Isn't that a pleasant thought?

Comment: @DanielSank It's not a bio question. We can assume the body is water and we are looking to minimize total volumetric dose

Comment: So what answers do you have, and what are your reasons?

Comment: Stay away from the source as much as possible.

Comment: @CuriousOne, your answer gave me quite a chuckle ... and I totally agree!

Comment: @DirkBruere considering only the question implied by the title I'd agree with you, but the question asks about maximizing "survival chances", which I guess is not the same thing as total volumetric dose.

Comment: @DanielSank Given that some parts of the body are more sensitive to radiation than others, probably true. When it comes to the feet first position I am also assuming legs are less sensitive to radiation than (say) the head